# Built-in function to get curand's curandStatus_t as string

Tags: c, random, cuda

For safe (or error-checked) CUDA calls (to functions like `cudaMemcpy`, `cudaMalloc`, `cudaFree`) we can define a [wrapper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14038589/what-is-the-canonical-way-to-check-for-errors-using-the-cuda-runtime-api), something like this:

```
#define cuSafe(ans) { gpuCuSafe((ans), __FILE__, __LINE__); }
inline void gpuCuSafe(cudaError_t code, const char *file, int line) {
    if (code != cudaSuccess) {
        fprintf(stderr,
                "GPU ERROR: '%s' in file %s (line %d)\n",
                cudaGetErrorString(code),  /* <----< */
                file,
                line);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
}
```

These CUDA function calls return values of type `cudaError_t`. We can call `cudaGetErrorString(cudaError_t c)` to get the error string that might provide information to the users and developers of the program (an error string explaining the error is better than an error code).

In the [cuRAND API Documentation](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/curand/index.html), they use a similar approach to wrap `curand` function calls. `curand` functions return values of type `curandStatus_t`.

**I am looking for a function that return a string representing the returned `curandStatus_t` value** ([could be](https://www3.nd.edu/~zxu2/acms60212-40212/CURAND_Library.pdf) `CURAND_STATUS_INITIALIZATION_FAILED`, `CURAND_STATUS_NOT_INITIALIZED`, etc), however, I couldn't find any function like that in the docs.

Just to be clear, what I want to be able to do is create a `curandSafe` wrapper (similar to the `cuSafe` example above)

```
#define curandSafe(ans) { gpuCuRandSafe((ans), __FILE__, __LINE__);}
inline void gpuCuRandSafe(curandStatus_t status, const char *file, int line) {
    if (status != CURAND_STATUS_SUCCESS) {
        fprintf(stderr,
                "GPU curand ERROR in file %s (line %d)\n",
                /*curandGetStatusString(status)*/  // OR SOMETHING LIKE THAT
                file,
                line);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
}
```

I am thinking about manually implementing it with a `switch-case`, but would like to know if there is a built-in function for it, so it takes care of possible, new status codes.

Comment: I still see no built-in function. The NVIDIA Samples files do not exist anymore.

Answer (score 4):

Oh, I think I found a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13041399/equivalent-of-cudageterrorstring-for-cublas). In the NVIDIA Samples [`cuda_helper.c`](https://github.com/pathscale/nvidia_sdk_samples/blob/master/vectorAdd/common/inc/helper_cuda.h#L504), you can see the function that handles `enum` values for `curand`.

```
#ifdef CURAND_H_
// cuRAND API errors
static const char *curandGetErrorString(curandStatus_t error)
{
    switch (error)
    {
        case CURAND_STATUS_SUCCESS:
            return "CURAND_STATUS_SUCCESS";

        case CURAND_STATUS_VERSION_MISMATCH:
            return "CURAND_STATUS_VERSION_MISMATCH";

        case CURAND_STATUS_NOT_INITIALIZED:
            return "CURAND_STATUS_NOT_INITIALIZED";

        case CURAND_STATUS_ALLOCATION_FAILED:
            return "CURAND_STATUS_ALLOCATION_FAILED";

        case CURAND_STATUS_TYPE_ERROR:
            return "CURAND_STATUS_TYPE_ERROR";

        case CURAND_STATUS_OUT_OF_RANGE:
            return "CURAND_STATUS_OUT_OF_RANGE";

        case CURAND_STATUS_LENGTH_NOT_MULTIPLE:
            return "CURAND_STATUS_LENGTH_NOT_MULTIPLE";

        case CURAND_STATUS_DOUBLE_PRECISION_REQUIRED:
            return "CURAND_STATUS_DOUBLE_PRECISION_REQUIRED";

        case CURAND_STATUS_LAUNCH_FAILURE:
            return "CURAND_STATUS_LAUNCH_FAILURE";

        case CURAND_STATUS_PREEXISTING_FAILURE:
            return "CURAND_STATUS_PREEXISTING_FAILURE";

        case CURAND_STATUS_INITIALIZATION_FAILED:
            return "CURAND_STATUS_INITIALIZATION_FAILED";

        case CURAND_STATUS_ARCH_MISMATCH:
            return "CURAND_STATUS_ARCH_MISMATCH";

        case CURAND_STATUS_INTERNAL_ERROR:
            return "CURAND_STATUS_INTERNAL_ERROR";
    }

    return "<unknown>";
}
#endif
```

Yet, it would be nice a built-in, thus version-independent solution for this problem.

Comment: The « similar question » asks about cuBLAS error status, while this post specifically asks for Curand.

Comment: Yes, and? I'm not sure I get your point. The tldr is that there was no built-in function, so you can create your own where you just convert the enum into a string by defining all the potential cases you know in a switch-case.

Yes, the similar question was for cublas, but the same principle and solution (or workaround) applies for curand, too.

Comment: Sorry I realized after that you answered your own post. I just wanted to say that the question was not already answered.